# How to say years period

Tags: time

I have trouble with a phrase:

> Potential investors study were carried out for the period 2008 - 2012.

This should mean that I've analyzed a documents published between 2008 and 2012. Is this the meaning that that conveys, or there is some better way to say what I mean to say here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The period 2008–2012" includes reports published from January 2008 to December 2012, and will certainly suffice if that is what you intend. That is, the years are **inclusive**.

Typophiles amongst us will recommend the use of an en-dash rather than a hyphen.

There **is** a problem with "Potential investors study were..." though. *Study* is singular and cannot take *were*. Either use "studies were" or "study was"; if you use "study was" you will also need an article *the/a* at the start of the sentence.